# Not able to debug ScheduledTaskAgent in VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-debugging

I am creating `ScheduledTaskAgent` as `dll` (selected in template while creating project as `Windows Phone Scheduled Task Agent`). When I use it in main project, background service is running properly, but I am not able to set `debug point`. Also, I used `Debugger.Break()`, still break point does not hit.

I am using Simulator. When I try to launch Background application every 10 seconds, it doesn't even in debug mode.

`ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pranit, you cannot debug Background task agents the same way you debug normal windows phone projects. Here are some techniques used.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Background_Agents_Debugging_Tips_on_Windows_Phone

I have used the ShellToast successfully to debug my agents. IMPORTANT: Remember to remove/comment all those code you add before deploying, or use #IFDEF statements.